# Is there a limit in Javascript to decimal places on big floats?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal

I'm facing the following issue/behavior:

```
console.log(1234567892012.123456);   // 1234567892012.1234
console.log(12345678920123.123456);  // 12345678920123.123
console.log(123456789201234.123456); // 123456789201234.12
```

What is causing this? Are decimal places limited for big numbers/floats?

Is it related to the IEEE 754 standard (as explained here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken))?

And finally - how can I come around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are seeing the inherent limitations of 64-bit floating point. If you really need more than two decimal places on a number as big as 123,456,789,201,234, you need some sort of extended arithmetic library. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library) has some suggestions and discussion.